# Cannot import name 'wrap_module'

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Im setting up an odoo community server and after adding and removing an addon, i am getting an error.

I have tried copying the odoo addons files back to the default install ones with no success.

```
Exception in thread odoo.service.cron.cron0:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 244, in target
    self.cron_thread(i)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 218, in cron_thread
    from odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron import ir_cron
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 82, in load_module
    exec(open(modfile, 'rb').read(), new_mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/__init__.py", line 8, in         
<module>
  from . import ir_actions
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 8, in 
<module>
  from odoo.tools import pycompat, wrap_module
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrap_module'
```

That is the error i am getting, ive tried using pip3 to install pycompat but it still dosnt work.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you running Odoo on python3,

on terminal `python3 path_to_odoo/./odoo-bin`
and clear the browser cache and try again.